# Kentico - NodeAlias length increased and future upgrade

Tags: kentico

I've just had the NodeAlias length increased from 50 to 200 characters - mostly for articles with long title. Now on second thought, I think this is not upgrade-proof, meaning if my Kentico is upgraded to version 10, the NodeAlias will possibly become 50 again. Is that correct?

If that's the case, what'll happen to all articles that have really long urls (longer than 50 characters)? Will the long urls be truncated automatically after upgrade and will the links to those pages will be broken?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kentico has a built-in and supported way of increasing the size of the NodeAlias. You can use `CMSMaxNodeAliasLength` web.config key along with some other minor changes. Here is a full list taken from the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Reference+-+Web.config+application+keys):

If you increase the key's value, you also need to:

- Edit the ~\CMSModules\Content\CMSDesk\Properties\Alias_List.aspx file and increase the MaxLength property of the txtAlias control.
- Delete the following view from your database:
  **View_CMS_Tree_Joined**
- Increase the nvarchar size for the NodeAlias column in the CMS_Tree database table.
- Recreate the deleted views. Run the following scripts:
  *~\App_Data\Install\SQL.zip\Objects\View_CMS_Tree_Joined.sql*
- Note: The maximum allowed length for the Node alias path is 450 characters, so the system may trim the alias path for pages deep in the content tree regardless of the allowed length.

Comment: Hi - My team mate has completed increasing the alias length, and it worked fine. My concern is mostly about the consequences, if any, of this especially for future Kentico upgrade.

Comment: You can never know what happens in a future, but since this is supported at this moment (and officially documented!) and many customers already rely on that you can be sure that this will be in soma form or another supported in upcoming versions.

Comment: Thanks Enn. My concern, and not sure if it's correct, is: Kentico 9 has 50 characters limit as default, then we changed it to 200. If Kentico 10/11/... continues having 50 characters as default, would our changes (of extending the alias to 200) be overwritten after upgrade? Do you know?

Comment: Hi Michelle, the upgrade will not change the length back to 50. Thats what the web.config setting is for :-) If this wouldnt be supported I would say that zes, there is the possibility of ovewriting your changes but  not when this is supported officially.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.